# Не могу оформить интерфейс для программы

Tags: java, gui, ip, сеть, интерфейс

*Нужно Разработать приложение, которое по заданному классу (А, В или С), ко-личеству подсетей N и максимальному количеству компьютеров М в подсети определяет маску для разбиения на подсети и список возможных IP-адресов подсетей. Если разбиение на подсети невозможно, приложение должно выдавать соответствующее сообщение об ошибке.*

Сама программа у меня уже есть, работает все нормально, но я хочу сделать для нее графический интерфейс, вроде бы заготовку сделал, но возникла проблема с выводом результатов в поля, которые находятся в программе.

Вот, но я почему то немогу понять как это сделать, я пытался каждую функцию сделать типа String и возвращать значения в main, а там результат той или иной ф-ции присвоить переменной result1, result1,... и передавать ее в d.setText(result1) и т.д.....

Но получилось так, что, во-первых, не все данные функции могут передаться через return, и в таком случае почему-то не выполняются необходимые проверки в функциях. И даже таким макаром почему-то результаты не передаются в поля вывода.

Подскажите пожалуйста что делать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы обратиться к методам `IP_Mask` надо объявить объект этого класса в вашем классе интерфейса. Далее вам будут доступны все не приватные методы объекта(к статическим методам имеют доступ только статические методы).

Соответственно у вас в классе `IP_Mask` все методы объявлены статическими и из  конструктора класса(который не является статическим) вы к ним доступа не получите.

Для решения этой проблемы сделайте все методы не статическими. Затем объявите объект класса `IP_Mask` и вызывайте свои методы:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        //Здесь нужно ввести и вывести результаты
        String type_class = a.getText();
        int networks = Integer.parseInt(b.getText());
        int hosts = Integer.parseInt(c.getText());

        IP_Mask ip_mask = new IP_Mask();
        ArrayList<Integer> mask = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            ip_mask.change_class(type_class, mask);
            ip_mask.check(type_class, networks, hosts);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ip_mask.print_IP(type_class);
        ip_mask.calculation_mask(type_class, hosts);
    }
});
```